# PowerShell functions load from function

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a module with several files with functions and module loader.

The example function:

`Function1.ps1`

```bsh
function Init() {
    echo "I am the module initialization logic"
}

function DoStuff() {
    echo "Me performing important stuff"
}
```

Module loader file:

`Module1.psm1`:

```bsh
$script:Functions = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\*.ps1 

function LoadModule {
    Param($path)
    foreach ($import in @($path)) {
        . $import.FullName
    }
}

LoadModule script:Functions

Init # function doesn't found
```

So I'm trying to load functions from the file `Function1.ps1` by procedure `LoadModule`.
Debugging `LoadModule` shows external functions loaded, but after finishing `LoadModule` procedure the functions become not accessible so script fails on `Init` row.

But rewritten module loader with no `LoadModule` function works fine

`Module1.psm1`:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\*.ps1 | %{
    . $import.FullName
}
Init # In this case - all works fine
```

So as I understand the file functions loaded from function placed in some isolated scope and to able to access them I need to add some scope flag.

Maybe somebody knows what I should add to make function `Init()` accessible from the module.pm1 script body but not make it accessible externally (without using `Export-ModuleMember`)?

Comment: The function dot-sources the files in a different scope. Why do you need that wrapper function in the first place? Just do what you do in your last code snippet.

Comment: Actually, the module loads private/public&shared function files and I moved code to separated function to not duplicate code because of  `LoadModule` contain extra logic like error handling and logging

Comment: If you need to call `Init` only once, then you can remove it after you call it.

Comment: @PetSerAl could you explain in more depth about removing after the call? Maybe it would be the solution

Comment: `Remove-Item Function:\Init`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found: During the execution of the `LoadModule` function, all registered functions will be added to [Functions Provider](http://%20[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_function_provider?view=powershell-6]v)

So from the  `LoadModule` function body they can be enumerated via  `Get-ChildItem -Path Function:`

```
[DBG]: PS > Get-ChildItem -Path Function:
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        C:
Function        Close-VSCodeHtmlContentView                        0.2.0      PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode
Function        Init                                               0.0        Module1
Function        ConvertFrom-ScriptExtent                           0.2.0    
Function        Module1                                            0.0        Module1
```

So we can store functions list to variable in the beginning of the invocation of the  `LoadModule`

```
$loadedFunctions =  Get-ChildItem -Path Function:
```

and after dot load notation retrieve the added function list

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Function: |  where { $loadedFunctions -notcontains $_ }
```

So the modified `LoadModule` function will look like:

```
function LoadModule {
    param ($path)
    $loadRef = Get-PSCallStack

    $loadedFunctions =  Get-ChildItem -Path Function:
    foreach ($import in @($path)) {
        . $import.FullName
    }
    $functions= Get-ChildItem -Path Function: | `
        Where-Object { $loadedFunctions -notcontains $_ } | `
        ForEach-Object{ Get-Item function:$_ }

    return $functions
}
```

the next step it just assigns the functions to list [More about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094650/is-there-a-function-pointer-or-array-of-functions-in-powershell)

```
$script:functions = LoadModule $script:Private ##Function1.ps1
$script:functions += LoadModule $script:PublicFolder
```

After this step, we can

- Invoke initalizer:

```bsh
    $initScripts = $script:functions| #here{ $_.Name -eq 'Initalize'} #filter
    $initScripts | ForEach-Object{ & $_ } ##execute
```

- and export Public functions:

```bsh
    $script:functions| `
    where { $_.Name -notlike '_*'  } |  ` # do not extport _Name functions
    %{ Export-ModuleMember -Function $_.Name}
```

Full code of the module load function I moved to the `ModuleLoader.ps1` file. And it can be found in the GitHub repo [PowershellScripts](https://github.com/stadub/PowershellScripts/blob/master/Shared-Functions/ModuleLoader.ps1)

And the complete version of the [`Moudule.psm1`](https://github.com/stadub/PowershellScripts/blob/master/Bookmarks/Bookmarks.psm1) file is

```
if($ModuleDevelopment){
    . $PSScriptRoot\..\Shared-Functions\ModuleLoader.ps1 "$PSScriptRoot"
}
else {
    . $PSScriptRoot\Shared\ModuleLoader.ps1 "$PSScriptRoot"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note: Edit 1, a clarification on what dot sourcing actually does, is included at the end.**

First up, you are intermingling terminology and usage for Functions and Modules. Modules, which have the .psm1 extension, should be imported into the terminal using the Import-Module cmdlet. When dot sourcing, such as what you are doing here, you should only be targeting script files which contain functions, which are files with the .ps1 extension.

I too am relatively new to PowerShell, and I ran into the same problem. After spending around an hour reading up on the issue I was unable to find a solution, but a lot of the information I found points to it being an issue of scope. So I created a test, utilising three files.

`foo.ps1`

```
function foo {
  Write-Output "foo"
}
```

`bar.psm1`

```
function bar {
  Write-Output "bar"
}
```

`scoping.ps1`

```
function loader {
    echo "dot sourcing file"
    . ".\foo.ps1"
    foo
    echo "Importing module"
    Import-Module -Name ".\bar.psm1"
    bar
}

foo
bar

loader

foo
bar

pause
```

Lets walk through what this script does.

First we define a dummy `loader` function. This isn't a practical loader, but it is sufficient for testing scopes and the availability of functions within files that are loaded. This function dot sources the ps1 file containing the function foo, and uses `Import-Module` for the file containing the function bar.

Next, we call on the functions `foo` and `bar`, which will produce errors, in order to establish that neither are within the current scope. While not strictly necessary, this helps to illustrate their absence.

Next, we call the `loader` function. After dot sourcing `foo.ps1`, we see `foo` successfully executed because `foo` is within the current scope of the `loader` function. After using `Import-Module` for `bar.psm1`, we see `bar` also successfully executed. Now we exit the scope of the `loader` function and return to the main script.

Now we see the execution of `foo` fail with an error. This is because we dot sourced `foo.ps1` within the scope of a function. However, because we imported `bar.psm1`, bar successfully executes. This is because modules are imported into the Global scope by default.

---

How can we use this to improve your `LoadModule` function? The main thing for this functionality is that you need to switch to using modules for your imported functions. Note that, from my testing, you cannot Import-Module the loader function; this only works if you dot source the loader.

`LoadModule.ps1`

```
function LoadModule($Path) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path" -Filter "*.psm1" -Recurse -File -Name| ForEach-Object {
        $File = "$Path$_"
        echo "Import-Module -Name $File"
        Import-Module -Name "$File" -Force
    }
}
```

And now in a terminal:

```
. ".\LoadModule.ps1"
LoadModule ".\"
foo
bar
```

---

### Edit 1: A further clarification on dot sourcing

Dot sourcing is equivalent to copy-pasting the contents of the specified file into the file preforming the dot source. The file performing the operation "imports" the contents of the target verbatim, performing no additional actions before proceeding to execute the "imported" code. e.g.

`foo.ps1`
`Write-Output "I am foo"

. ".\bar.ps1"`

`bar.ps1`

```
Write-Output "I am bar"
```

is effectively

```
Write-Output "I am foo"
Write-Output "I am bar"
```

Comment: The `Import-Module` syntax doesn't fit for me because the `Module1.psm1` it is actually a module which aim is to load other functions into the module. And if the module will use other functions importing with `Import-Module` the module won't be able to export them to environment.

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for the "modules load" and "a dot syntax" detailed explanation

Comment: If you use it as I have described, it should work for your use-case. Source a .ps1 file containing your module loader, and then invoke the module loader to import your remaining functions as modules. Importing a module which then imports more modules does not seem to work. Sourcing a function which then imports modules does work.

Comment: I should also note that .ps1 and .psm1 files are technically the same. You're not missing anything there. The distinction is a semantic one, which encourages better code practices. Your reusable code should be in modules which you import, and your use-case-specific code should be in .ps1 files which you execute. These .ps1 files then have access to your reusable modules.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You don't actually need to use Import-Module. So long as you have the modules in your $env:PSModulePath PowerShell will autoload any exported functions when they are first called. [Source](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-05-27-Powershell-module-building-basics/#module-autoloading).

Depending on the specifics of your use case, there's another method you can use. This method addresses when you want to mass-import modules into a PowerShell session.

When you start PowerShell it looks at the values of the environment variable $PSModulePath in order to determine where it should look for modules. It then looks under this directory for directories containing psm1 and psd1 files. You can modify this variable during the session, and then import modules by name. Here's an example, using what I've added to my PowerShell `profile.ps1` file:

```
$MyPSPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments") + "\WindowsPowerShell"

$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";$MyPSPath\Custom\Modules"

Import-Module `
    -Name Confirm-Directory, `
    Confirm-File, `
    Get-FileFromURL, `
    Get-RedirectedURL, `
    Get-RemoteFileName, `
    Get-ReparseTarget, `
    Get-ReparseType, `
    Get-SpecialPath, `
    Test-ReparsePoint
```

In the event that you're new to PowerShell profiles (they're pretty much the same as Unix's `~/.profile` file), you can find:

1. more information about PowerShell profiles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.0).
2. a summary of what profile files are used and when [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/).

While this may not seem as convenient as an auto-loader, installing & importing modules is the intended and accepted approach for this. Unless you have a specific reason not to, you should try to follow the established standards so that you aren't later fighting your way out of bad habits.

You can also [modify the registry](https://tomtalks.blog/2013/06/powershell-add-a-persistent-module-path-to-envpsmodulepath/) to achieve this.